# Stack implementation using arrays in Java

Tags: java, array, stack

Could someone please review my code and let me know if there is any scope for optimization for better performance.

```
package com.gmail.practice;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stacks {

private int top;
int size;
int[] stack;

public Stacks(int arraysize)
{
    size = arraysize;
    stack = new int[size];
    top = -1;
}

public void push(int value)
{
    if(top == size-1)
    {
        System.out.println("the value cant be pushed: Stack underflow");
    }
    else{
        top = top+1;
        stack[top] = value;
    }
}

public void pop()
{
    if(top > size-1)
    {
        System.out.println("stack is overflow");
    }else{
        top = top-1;
        System.out.println("current top value is " + " " +stack[top]);
        System.out.println("the popped value is" + " " + stack[top+1]);
    }

}

public void display()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        System.out.println(stack[i]);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Stacks s = new Stacks(5);
    s.push(10);
    s.push(15);
    s.push(19);
    s.push(3);
    s.pop();
    s.push(4);
    s.display();
    s.pop();
    s.pop();
    s.display();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106609/27975)'s to your later question, there is limited value in this class as elements cannot be easily retrieved.

Putting aside the obvious improvements to the seemingly toy implementations, you have a mistake in describing whether the stack has 'overflow' or 'underflow': the meanings should be inversed. When you try to `push(int)` to a full stack, that is known as an [overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), and you need to check whether the stack is empty when `pop()`-ping instead of checking for 'overflows'.

To better indicate error conditions such as those mentioned above, you can make use of [throwing `Exception`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) instead of a simple `System.out.println()`. In fact, I will suggest using `System.err.println()` at the very least to differentiate between normal and error 'outputs'.

A Java 8 way of printing the contents of the stack is to use [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-):

```
public void display() {
    Arrays.stream(stack).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This uses `System.out.println(int)` as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to print each `int` value on the console.

Simply running through some test operations in the `main()` method is also barely enough, you should consider proper [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) techniques such as using a testing framework that can [arrange-act-assert](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) for you.

Last but not least, you should also take a look at the standard JDK classes' stack implementations for greater inspiration, such as the [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just throw exceptions instead of writing something to the console? Also make use of generics? It is highly unlikely that `Stack` will be used only for integers. A stack implementation using arrays is good, but most of the time people also use `LinkedList` to implement it, so that you do not have to resize once you exceed `INITIAL_CAPACITY`. It all comes down to the user's choice.

Here are two implementations which can be useful:

[Array implementation of Java Stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111944/array-implementation-of-java-stack?rq=1)

[My own Stack Implementation in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140436/my-own-stack-implementation-in-java)