# Implementing two stacks using single array in java

Tags: java, array, stack

Please review the code

```
package com.gmail.practice;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class StacksForTwo {

    int size;
    int[] stack;
    int top1;
    int top2;

    public StacksForTwo(int arraysize)
    {
        size = arraysize;
        stack = new int[size];
        top1 = -1;
        top2 = size;        
    }

    public void push1(int x)
    {
        if(top1 < top2-1)
        {
        top1++;
        stack[top1] = x;        
        }else{
            System.out.println("stackoverflow");
        }
    }

    public void push2(int y)
    {
        if(top1 < top2-1)
        {
            top2--;
            stack[top2] = y;
        }else{
            System.out.println("stack overflow");
        }
    }

    public void pop1()
    {
        if(top1 >= 0)
        {
            top1--;
            System.out.println("The popped out number is"+" "+stack[top1+1]);
        }else{
            System.out.println("stack underflow");
        }
    }

    public void pop2()
    {
        if(top2 < size)
        {
            top2++;
            System.out.println("The popped out number is"+" "+stack[top2+1]);
        }else{
            System.out.println("stack underflow");
        }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stack));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StacksForTwo sft = new StacksForTwo(10);
        sft.push1(4);
        sft.push1(5);
        sft.push1(3);
        sft.push1(2);
        sft.push2(6);
        sft.push2(4);
        sft.display();
        sft.push2(8);
        sft.push1(2);
        sft.push2(6);
        sft.push2(4);
        sft.push2(8);
        sft.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Depending on your inputs i will try more things.

Comment: (Beyond declaring `package com.gmail.practice`,) Neither code nor question state the purpose of coding this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go for

```
interface Stack {
    boolean isEmpty();
    int pop();
    void push(int x);
}
```

And then make a class providing two Stacks.

Also create a counter to detect when both stacks are full. This can be done with an `AtomicInteger` (**thread-safeness**) counting the free array slots.

```
public class StackPair {
    public final Stack firstStack = new Stack { ... };
    public final Stack secondStack = new Stack { ... };
    public StackPair(int capacity) { ... }
```

---

In StackPair the single array and an AtomicInteger freeEntries. In both Stack implementations access to the array and freeEntries.

Comment: The question says implementing two stacks using a `single` array.

Comment: @CodeYogi I build on the solution of the question. but I will extend the answer. Meaning that StackPair contains the single array.

Answer (score 6):

This code is a WOM implementation of a stack - Write Only Memory. Normally it's done as a joke. The only way to get the data out of the stack is to parse the standard output waiting for `println` statements with the values in them.

I can understand that your code is here for you to watch the process happening, but beyond that there's not much real functionality in here. I encourage you to use proper code where the `pop()` methods actually return their result, and the calling code is the code that prints the output. Alternatively, I strongly recommend you use the IDE's debugger interface to step through your code so you can watch things happen that way.

Having said all that, here are some general comments:

1. your instance variables are not private, and should be.
2. the `size` and `stack` variables should also be final
3. instead of having a `display()` method, just override the `toString()`
4. `push1`, and `pop1` et all should probably be renamed to `pushLeft` and `pushRight`, or really anythong other than 1 and 2. You used the variables `x` and `y` so why not `pushX` and `pushY`?

Comment: Fields are default scope and can be accessed from classes in same package, anyway its pretty WOM. If he follow your suggestions its perfectly WOM.

Answer (score 1):

You are inconsistent with your brace and indentation style. If in doubt, pick an auto-formatter and work with that. Most IDEs come with one, just use that for the beginning.

---

```
public class StacksForTwo
```

That's a bad name for the class. A "pair" is a better word to use.

---

```
int size;
int[] stack;
int top1;
int top2;
```

Why are these variables package-private?

---

```
public StacksForTwo(int arraysize)
```

`arraysize` is an incorrect name for this variable, `size` would be correct as that an array is being used is only an implementation detail and should not be shown through the API.

```
public StacksForTwo(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    ...
```

Also it should be made clear that the size is the size for *all* items.

---

```
public void push1(int x)
```

`x` is a bad name for this variable, it should rather be `item` or `value`.

---

```
System.out.println("stackoverflow");
```

It would be better to throw an exception in this case.

---

```
public void pop1()
...
    System.out.println("The popped out number is"+" "+stack[top1+1]);
```

This method should return the popped number and leave the printing to the outside code.

---

```
top1--;
System.out.println("The popped out number is"+" "+stack[top1+1]);
```

For easier reading, you can roll that into one operation:

```
return stack[top1--];
```

---

```
System.out.println("stack underflow");
```

This should also be an exception.

---

```
public void display()
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stack));
}
```

That should be the overridden `toString` method.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Ideally, your main class is a different one.

---

```
StacksForTwo sft = new StacksForTwo(10);
```

Please don't go fancy with names, always pick the stupid and simple ones, like `stacksForTwo` or `stacks`. Down in a 1000+ line method, having to work with shortened names and/or acronyms as names is a nightmare you don't want to find yourself, because you constantly have to map the names to something that makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have to second [Joop Eggen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106622/93149) and put *providing a proper interface* first. With Java botching it right from the start (ab)using an abstract class in pre-*Collections Framework* times to go and  *not* create `FIFO`, but decorate `Deque`, I guess there is no way getting an `interface Stack` right. I ended up on the **fat** side:

```
/** <code>Stack</code> with quintessential <code>push()</code>
 * and <code>pop()</code>. */
public interface Stack<E>
    extends Iterable<E> // don't know how else to provide a default iterator() 
    // java.util.Collection<E> if that wasn't FAT
{
    /** A <code>Stack</code> with a buddy allowing access to the latter. */
    interface Buddy<E> extends Stack<E> {
        Buddy<E> buddy();
    }
 // essential
    E pop();
    /** @throws IllegalStateException if <code>element</code> not accepted */
    default void push(E element) {
        checkRecursion();
        if (!offer(element))
            throw new IllegalStateException("element offered not accepted");
    }
 // important if pop() throws when empty
    default boolean isEmpty() { return size() <= 0; }

 // secondary
    /** <em>Not</em> specifying overrides not to throw the likes of
     *  <code>IllegalStateException</code> instead,
     *   the default implementation returns <code>null</code> if empty.
     * Fails catastrophically if pop() or push()
     *  fail in between modifying and restoring state. */
    default E peek() {
        if (isEmpty())
            return null;
        E top = pop();
        push(top);
        return top;
    }

    /** @return accepted */
    default boolean offer(E element) { push(element); return true; }
    int size();

 // support
    /** For consistency, the <code>Iterator<E></code> returned
     *  should <em>not</em> allow <code>remove()</code>
     *  (but, possibly, for the top element). */
    @Override
    default java.util.Iterator<E> iterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    default void checkRecursion() {
        try {
            if (Stack.class == getClass().getMethod("offer",
                    new Class [] { Object.class }).getDeclaringClass())
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "neither offer nor push implemented");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}


// for the hell of it: an implementation
// Don't do as I do: Do as I say (regarding doc comment _everything_ public)
/** Not synchronised. */
public class Stack_<E> implements Stack.Buddy<E> {
    protected final AtomicInteger total;
    protected Object[] elements; // might be final but for resizing
    protected Stack.Buddy<E> buddy;
    @Override
    public Stack.Buddy<E> buddy() {
        if (null == buddy)
            buddy = new Stack_.Buddy<>(this, elements, total);
        return buddy;
    }

    protected int top;
    @Override
    public int size() { return top + 1; }
    protected int nextTop() { return ++top; }
    protected int prevTop() { return --top; }
 // Alternative to overridden <code>top<code> manipulation:
 //  overridden accessors
 // E at(int i) { return (E) elements[i]; }
 // void set(int i, E e) { elements[i] = e; }

 // An implementation growing elements on demand should conceivably
 //  provide a default constructor (using a default capacity).
    public Stack_(int arraysize) {
        elements = new Object[arraysize];
        total = new AtomicInteger();
        buddy = null;
        top = -1;
    }
    protected Stack_(Object[] elements, AtomicInteger total) {
        this.elements = elements;
        this.total = total;
    }
    public void push(E x) {
        if (total.incrementAndGet() <= elements.length)
            elements[nextTop()] = x;
        else {
            total.decrementAndGet();
            throw new IllegalStateException(
//          System.err.println(
                "no space");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public E pop() {
        E value = peek();
        elements[top] = null;  // long lived containers should support GC
        prevTop();
        return value;
    }
    @Override
    public E peek() { return (E) elements[top]; }
    @Override
    public String toString() {  // might cache asList
        return java.util.Arrays.asList(elements).subList(0, top).toString();
    }


    static class Buddy<E> extends Stack_<E> {
        public Buddy(Stack_<E> buddy, Object[] elements, AtomicInteger total) {
            super(elements, total);
            this.buddy = buddy;
            top = elements.length;
        }
        @Override
        protected int nextTop() { return --top; }
        @Override
        protected int prevTop() { return ++top; }
        @Override
        public int size() { return elements.length - top; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(2+4*size());
            String sep = "[";
            for (int i = elements.length ; top <= --i ; sep = ", ")
                sb.append(sep).append(String.valueOf(elements[i]));
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        }
    }
}
```

(Considering what is ranked *secondary*, the remaining difference may be)
`Stack.Buddy<E>`: a stack supporting getting a *buddy*.
Using a proper interface gets "the member naming issue" out of the way.

Next comes my hobby horse: comment, at least *doc comment everything public*.

Then, there is *code duplication* between `push[12]()` & `pop[12]()`
- for 1½ exercises in avoiding it, see the implementation above.

Avoid having business functions communicate, e.g. using `System.in/out`.

Comment: (This is just me pondering to try and present a half decent implementation of poly-phase merge sort.)