# Command line parser only with switches (if-less)

Tags: c#, parsing, comparative-review, console

I've been playing around with **C# 7** and created this *if-less* and `switch`-only command-line parser. What do you think of it? Can it be made more C# 7 or otherwise improved? Is the new `switch` a good alternative to the *old* `if/else`?

---

It splits a string by `|=|:` *(space, equal-sign, colon)* into tokens (unless escaped) and removes quotes from quoted parts.

```
public static void Parse7(string text)
{
    var escapableChars = new HashSet<char> { '\\', '"', '=', ':' };
    var separators = new HashSet<char> { ' ', '=', ':' };
    var tokens = new List<string>();
    var token = new StringBuilder();
    var escapeMode = false;
    var quoted = false;

    bool IsUnquotedSeparator(char c) => separators.Contains(c) && !quoted;
    bool IsTokenEmpty() => token.Length == 0;

    foreach (var c in text ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text)))
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\\' when !escapeMode:
                escapeMode = true;
                // Don't eat escape-char yet.
                break;

            case '"':
                quoted = !quoted;
                // Don't eat quotes.
                break;

            default:
                switch (escapeMode)
                {
                    case true:
                        switch (escapableChars.Contains(c))
                        {
                            case false:
                                // Eat escape-char because it doesn't escape anything.
                                token.Append('\\');
                                break;
                        }
                        // Eat escaped-char.
                        token.Append(c);
                        escapeMode = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        switch (IsUnquotedSeparator(c))
                        {
                            case true when !IsTokenEmpty():
                                // Eat token.
                                tokens.Add(token.ToString());
                                token.Clear();
                                break;

                            case true:
                                // Don't eat separators.
                                break;

                            default:
                                // Eat any other char.
                                token.Append(c);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    switch (IsTokenEmpty())
    {       
        case false:
            // Eat the last token.
            tokens.Add(token.ToString());
            break;
    }

    tokens.Dump(); // LINQPad
}
```

Example:

```
var cmd = @"foo.exe --bar=""baz"" --qux --baar\=baaz --quux";
Parse7(cmd);
```

Result:

> ```
> foo.exe 
> --bar 
> baz 
> --qux 
> --baar=baaz 
> --quux
> ```

---

For comparison purposes this is the *classic* version:

```
public static void Parse(string text)
{
    var escapableChars = new HashSet<char> { '\\', '"', '=', ':' };
    var separators = new HashSet<char> { ' ', '=', ':' };
    var tokens = new List<string>();
    var token = new StringBuilder();
    var escapeMode = false;
    var quoted = false;

    foreach (var c in text)
    {                   
        if (c == '\\' && !escapeMode)
        {
            escapeMode = true;
            // Don't eat escape-char yet.
            continue;
        }

        if (escapeMode)
        {
            if (escapableChars.Contains(c)) token.Append(c);
            else token.Append('\\').Append(c);
            escapeMode = false;
            // Escape-char already eaten.
            continue;
        }

        if (c == '"')
        {
            quoted = !quoted;
            // Don't eat quotes.
            continue;               
        }

        if (separators.Contains(c) && !quoted)
        {
            tokens.Add(token.ToString());
            token.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            token.Append(c);
        }
    }
    if (token.Length > 0) tokens.Add(token.ToString());

    tokens.Dump(); // LINQPad
}
```

Comment: I've never been a big fan of nested switch statements, just because of how it reads. Are you trying to get an optimized refactoring (better performance)? Or just want to put a new C#7 feature through the meat grinder? :)

Comment: @KirkWoll yes, it does - both in Visual Studio 2017 and in LINQPad-beta. It's working code.

Comment: @Svek It's not just a nested switch ;-) The new switch can do so much more. I find the new code is easier to understand then the one with _continue_. It feels more natural without jumps and I was able to optimize the switch-version mutch quicker then the if-one (they are currently only 95% identical because the if-s and continue-s make me headaches). I'm not trying to get a better performance (yet) but the new code seems to run slightly faster. I'm experimenting with the new syntax in the first place to see what is possible ;-)

Comment: @KirkWoll It's a ReSharper thing. It doesn't understand C# 7 yet. There is a beta version but I didn't try it. I disabled code inspections for now. It compiles and works but R# complains. I had the same problem with something like [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35435353#35435353) the entire block inside the `using` statement was shown as inactive and unreachable.

Comment: Thanks @t3chb0t, that's it exactly!  Appreciate your taking the time to elaborate. :)

Comment: I'm wondering if the conditional statement at your "foreach (var c in text ?? throw new ..)" gets hit each pass - or does it only get hit the one time?

Comment: @Svek It should only check once, as the null coalescing operator is comparing against `text`. If it helps you to understand, you can read it as `foreach(var c in (text ?? throw ...))`. Plus it wouldn't make sense to have a `(char)null` anyways, at least for this example.

Comment: @t3chb0t To be fair, the `continue` is no much different than the `break` in term of flow control, so to each his own. However, I may add that a `switch` statement indents the inner code block by 2, while `if` statement indents it by 1, which is an eyesore in my opinion. Generally, I pick the control mechanism that requires me to do the least amount of typing while weighting the aesthetic and *what feels right*. I found your `if` example easier to read, than your `switch` one. However, we are comparing nested `switches`against single layer `if`.

Comment: Another consideration is your switch statement for your booleans, it seems like overkilll to use a switch between true/default (also reads difficult)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If vs switch

If-statements and switch-statements are both "selections" ([control structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)). Selections produce [abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)) in the control flow as you loose the information "which way was selected" afterwards.

Using one or the other does not change the control flow. So after all both are either good or evil or anything beneath it. Depending on the programming language they may be different in the assertions they give when mapping a datastructure to a control flow. But if you know that a switch statement serves the same purpose as an if statement readability becomes a matter of ***habituation*** and ***subjectivity***. That is why I say also "switch" when I say "if".

You may have new syntactical sugar to express "selections" that will be more compact but it remains a selection.

## Abstraction

The only interesting thing we are able to change to a more flexible structure is the abstraction that will be represented as abstract classes or interfaces with their concrete implementations. If you make proper decisions for abstractions they become beneficial (e.g. readability).

## Parsing

A combination of the [interpreter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) and the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) will provide a solid structure for parsing things from various sources. The state pattern will guide your control flow through different compilation units that can be independently arranged. The interpreter will gather the instructions from the "state machine" and executes whatever it should do.

To be fair: You will finally not have less if-statements and a lot more compilation units. But you will have a beneficial structure that decouples nested if-statements in an elegant way to be able to recompose the control flow. So you will get the flexibility to meet future parsing requirements when extending the interpreted language.

Here we have a beneficial structure that ***leads objectively to better readability and understandability*** as a concrete state focussed only one level of if-statements, is isolated from other states (other isolated if statements) and encapsulated. Your internal stack is less loaded to see and understand the movable parts within the state than an equivalent nested If-then-else cascade.

What you do with this is applying the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). A state is responsible to only decide to which state to go next residing in one level of abstraction that definitely is affecting readability.

## References

Oracle for example provide state machine like diagrams to define the syntax of their SQL variant:

[SELECT (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm)

Another representation but effectively the same purpose PostgresSQL Documentation is following within the synopsis:

[SELECT (Postgres)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html)

Another way to formalize the syntax in a developers style is using the UML notations for a state chart:

[UML state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)

The base theory for all of this are:

[Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net)

A very simple schema to get an idea how to implement it I provided here:

[Infix to Postfix Formula Parser Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112091/infix-to-postfix-formula-parser-java)

Comment: These are very interesting points, especially the interpreter and state patterns. I'll need some time to study them and I'll try to implement them in the command-line parser.

Answer (score 2):

A small suggestion, but your `switch` statement for `booleans` seems a bit overkill (and in most cases quite hard to read)

Consider your code block here on how you are using the switch statement for a true/false:

> ```
> switch (escapableChars.Contains(c))
> {
>     case false:
>         // Eat escape-char because it doesn't escape anything.
>         token.Append('\\');
>         break;
> }
> // Eat escaped-char.
> token.Append(c);
> escapeMode = false;
> ```

This would be easier to read if you used an `if` statement

```
if(!escapableChars.Contains(c)) token.Append('\\');
// Eat escaped-char.
token.Append(c);
escapeMode = false;
```