# My own Stack Implementation in Java

Tags: java, stack

Please review my `Stack` implementation and let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
public class StackImplementation<T> {
private StackNode<T> top;
private StackNode<T> head;
private int size;

static class StackNode<T> {
    private T value;
    private StackNode<T> next;

    public StackNode(T val) {
        this.value = val;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public StackNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(StackNode<T> nextNode) {
        this.next = nextNode;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(value == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        return value.toString();
    }
}

public StackImplementation() {
    head = new StackNode(0);
    size = 0;
    top = head;
}

public void push(T val) {
    StackNode<T> cur = new StackNode<T>(val);
    cur.setNext(top);
    top = cur;
    size++;
    return;
}

public StackNode<T> peek() {
    return top;
}

public T pop() {
    if(size == 0 || top.getNext() == null) {
        throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
    }

    T poppedElement = peek().getValue();
    this.top = this.top.getNext();
    size--;
    return poppedElement;
}

public void clear() {
    head.setNext(null);
    top = head;
    size = 0;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StackNode<T> cur = head.getNext();
    sb.append(cur.getValue() + "->");
    while(!cur.equals(top)) {
        sb.append(cur.getValue() + "->");
    }
    sb.append("null");
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackImplementation<Integer> st = new StackImplementation<>();
    System.out.println(st.size());
    //st.pop(); //NoSuchElementException
    st.push(1);
    st.push(10);
    st.push(100);
    System.out.println(st.size());
    System.out.println(st.peek());
    System.out.println(st.pop());
    System.out.println(st.peek());
    System.out.println(st.pop());
    System.out.println(st.isEmpty());
    st.clear();
    System.out.println(st.isEmpty());
    System.out.println(st.size());
    //st.pop(); //NoSuchElementException
}}
```

Comment: If you dislike the format of my answer, let me know and I will revise it.

Comment: It is very well put up. And very helpful. Thank you coderodde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added comments directly in the code whenever I have something to say.

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Objects;

// 'Implementation' does not add any information.
//public class StackImplementation<T> {
public class Stack<T> {

    private StackNode<T> top;
    // Not really needing 'head':
    // private StackNode<T> head;
    private int size;

    // Added 'private'. Now even the code in the same package cannot get to
    // 'StackNode':
    private static class StackNode<T> {

        private T value;
        private StackNode<T> next;

        // Really do not need 'public' since this class is visible ONLY in the 
        // 'Stack':
        /*public*/ StackNode(T val) {
            this.value = val;
            // JVM already initializes reference fields to 'null' by default:
            // this.next = null;
        }

        // Same argument against use of 'public' as in the constructor:
        /*public*/ T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        /*public*/ StackNode<T> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        /*public*/ void setNext(StackNode<T> nextNode) {
            this.next = nextNode;
        }

        // '@Override' would not hurt here. If you somehow mistyped the name of
        // the method being override, and it has a @Override, compiler will 
        // notify you:
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // You can do just:
            return Objects.toString(value);
            // if (value == null) {
            //     return "null";
            // }
            // return value.toString();
        }
    }

    // In this case you can omit the constructor altogether. JVM initializes
    // reference fields to 'null' by default, and integer fields to zero by 
    // default:
    // public StackImplementation() {
    //     head = new StackNode(0);
    //     size = 0;
    //     top = head;
    // }

    public void push(T val) {
        // Since Java 7, you can do "diamond inference":
        StackNode<T> cur = new StackNode<>(val);
        // StackNode<T> cur = new StackNode<T>(val);
        cur.setNext(top);
        top = cur;
        size++;
        // You can remove the 'return' whenever it is the very last statement of
        // a method:
        // return;
    }

    // peek() does not return the topmost node but rather its value:
    public T peek() {
        checkNotEmpty();
        return top.getValue();
    }

    public T pop() {
        checkNotEmpty();
        // if (size == 0 || top.getNext() == null) {
        //     throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
        // }

        T poppedElement = top.getValue();
        // Can omit 'this' here:
        top = top.getNext();
        // this.top = this.top.getNext();
        size--;
        return poppedElement;
    }

    public void clear() {
        top = null;
        size = 0;
        // The rest is up to garbage collector.
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return "[]";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[").append(top.getValue());
        StackNode<T> node = top.getNext();

        while (node != null) {
            sb.append(" -> ").append(node.getValue());
            node = node.getNext();
        }

        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    private void checkNotEmpty() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
        System.out.println(st.size());
        st.push(1);
        st.push(10);
        st.push(100);
        st.push(null);
        System.out.println(st);
        System.out.println(st.size());
        System.out.println(st.peek());
        System.out.println(st.pop());
        System.out.println(st.peek());
        System.out.println(st.pop());
        System.out.println(st.isEmpty());
        st.clear();
        System.out.println(st.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(st.size());
        st.peek(); // Exception!
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I incorporated your valuable comments and came up with my own queue implementation. Do let me know what you think. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/my-own-queue-implementation-in-java 

Also I have named the class as "QueueImplementation" because, I do not want to mistakenly include my "Queue" implementation instead of the one provided by "Java", as I would always prefer to use that.

Comment: Could also shed some light on as to when we should override equals and hashcode method.

Comment: @SandeepKumar Sorry for answering that late. What comes to **`equals`** and **`hashCode`**, you should override them for a class whose objects are to be put into hashtable-based datastructures, such as **`(Linked)HashSet`**, **`(Linked)HashMap`**. If, however, you have to put your objects into a **`TreeMap`** or **`TreeSet`**, make sure you override **`equals`** and **`compareTo`**.

Answer (score 0):

The `StackNode` class can be considerably shortened using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). You may not want to use Lombok, but I think it is something you should consider. Specifically a lot of your setters and getters are trivial which allows you to simplify the code considerably:

From this:

```
static class StackNode<T> {
    private T value;
    private StackNode<T> next;

    public StackNode(T val) {
        this.value = val;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public StackNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(StackNode<T> nextNode) {
        this.next = nextNode;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(value == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

To:

```
static class StackNode<T> {
    @Getter private T value;
    @Setter @Getter private StackNode<T> next;

    public StackNode(T val) {
        this.value = val;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(value == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```