# My own Queue Implementation in Java

Tags: java, queue

Please review my `Queue` implementation and let me know if you have any suggestions. I am not returning an exception for any of the methods defined here. As we know the exception is thrown only for `add` and `remove` functions and not for `poll` or `offer` functions.

```
    public class QueueImplementation<T> {
    private QueueNode<T> first;
    private QueueNode<T> last;
    private int size;

    private static class QueueNode<T> {
        private T val;
        private QueueNode<T> next;

        public QueueNode(T val) {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public void setNext(QueueNode<T> nextNode) {
            next = nextNode;
        }

        public QueueNode<T> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if(val == null) {
                return "null";
            }
            return val.toString();
        }

    }

    public void offer(T val) {
        QueueNode<T> cur = new QueueNode(val);
        if(size == 0) {
            cur.setNext(first);
            first = cur;
            last = cur;
            size++;
            return;
        }

        last.setNext(cur);
        last = cur;
        size++;
    }

    public T peek() {
        if(!isEmpty()) {
            return first.getValue();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public QueueNode<T> poll() {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        QueueNode<T> cur = first;
        first = first.getNext();
        size--;
        return cur;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public void clear() {
        size = 0;
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(size == 0) {
            return "[]";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        QueueNode<T> cur = first;
        sb.append(cur.getValue() + "<-");

        while(cur.getNext() != null && !cur.equals(last)) {
            sb.append(cur.getNext().getValue() + "<-");
            cur = cur.getNext();
        }

        return sb.append("null").toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueImplementation<Integer> q = new QueueImplementation<>();
        System.out.println(q.size());
        System.out.println(q.poll()); //returns null;
        System.out.println(q.peek()); //return null;
        q.offer(1);
        q.offer(10);
        q.offer(100);
        System.out.println(q.size());
        System.out.println(q.peek());
        System.out.println(q.poll());
        System.out.println(q.size());
        System.out.println(q.peek());
        System.out.println(q.poll());
        System.out.println(q.poll());
        System.out.println(q.size());
        System.out.println(q.poll());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please discontinue putting "thanks" in posts.  Only show your gratitude with upvotes and accepts.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if(size == 0) {
        return "[]";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    QueueNode<T> cur = first;
    sb.append(cur.getValue() + "<-");

    while(cur.getNext() != null && !cur.equals(last)) {
        sb.append(cur.getNext().getValue() + "<-");
        cur = cur.getNext();
    }

    return sb.append("null").toString();
}
```

Empty stack prints `"[]"`, stack with one element prints `1<-null`. Where are the surrounding brackets? Also, you can use a do-while loop here to prevent needing to specify how to print twice:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if(size == 0) {
        return "[]";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    QueueNode<T> cur = first;

    do {
        sb.append(cur.getValue() + "<-");
        cur = cur.getNext();
    } while(cur != null);

    return sb.append("null").toString();
}
```

It also vastly simplifies the iteration.

---

```
public void offer(T val) {
    QueueNode<T> cur = new QueueNode(val);
    if(size == 0) {
        cur.setNext(first);
        first = cur;
        last = cur;
        size++;
        return;
    }

    last.setNext(cur);
    last = cur;
    size++;
}
```

This could be simplified to reduce duplication - step 1, making the else case explicit...

```
public void offer(T val) {
    QueueNode<T> cur = new QueueNode(val);
    if(size == 0) {
        cur.setNext(first);
        first = cur;
        last = cur;
        size++;
    } else {
        last.setNext(cur);
        last = cur;
        size++;
    }
}
```

Step two, moving similar instructions into the shared area.

```
public void offer(T val) {
    QueueNode<T> cur = new QueueNode(val);
    if(size == 0) {
        cur.setNext(first);
        first = cur;
    } else {
        last.setNext(cur);
    }
    last = cur;
    size++;
}
```

Additionally, you can make use of `isEmpty()` here for increased clarity.

---

```
public QueueNode<T> poll() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    QueueNode<T> cur = first;
    first = first.getNext();
    size--;
    return cur;
}
```

`poll()` is returning internal nodes. You want to return the value instead. Don't expose your internal nodes. Use exceptions for indicating pulling from an empty queue.